# Momentum and position operators in Schrödinger representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

I was going through some intro notes on path integral (for QFT), and am stuck with this equation for position and momentum in Schrödinger (position) representation,
$$ \hat{1} =\int dq\;\left|q\right>\left<q\right|, $$
$$ \hat{Q} =\int dq\;\left|q\right>q\left<q\right|, $$
$$ \hat{P} = \int dq\;\left|q\right>\bigg(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\bigg)\left<q\right|  .$$

It seems quite a simple thing, but am stuck somewhere, am sorry if it is a ridiculous one.

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Do you not understand the meaning of the expressions? How they come about? How to calculate with them?

Comment: Nope, I am afraid I don't even understand what capital Q and the small q 's differ by.

Comment: Try googling "completeness relation" or "spectral theorem."  You'll find numerous descriptions of what these expressions mean.

Comment: @joshphysics : I thought, completeness would mean $ \int dq\;\left|q\right>\left<q\right| = \mathcal{\hat 1} $

Comment: @user35952 Yes, that's right, but often googling a related term is the best way to get the results you want.  Notice also that I included "spectral theorem."

Comment: @user35952 Try also "spectral decomposition."